# Add remove option back in selectlist

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new in JavaScript and jQuery. I have a dropdown list retrieved from database. When I select any one, it add to as text, and remove from dropdown list. And placed a button to each text, if I want to remove any one. When click remove button, it append again in select list.

My problem is that when I removed any text option, it append back to the dropdown select list as blank option.

I want to append removed option back to the select list as text. I don't know where I did wrong thing.

```js
      $(document).ready(function() {
         $('#location').click(function() {
            if($(this).find( "option:selected").val() != 0) {
               $('#Locality').append("<div><input type='text' class='field' value='" + $(this).find( "option:selected").text() + "' disabled/><input type=\"button\" class='removeBtn' value=\"Remove\" id=\"removeBtn\" /></div>");
               $(this).find("option:selected").remove();
             }
             $('.removeBtn').on('click', function () { 
                $(this).parent().remove();
                $("#location").append('<option>' + $(this).parent().text() + '</option>');
             });
          });
      });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Locality">
       <select name="supplyLocation" id="location" >
           <option value="0">Select Locality</option>
       </select>
    </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

this worked for me but when you put it back in the select menu it will be the last option, here's a JsFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/9tLc1pa4/1/

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('#location').change(function() {
        if($(this).find( "option:selected").val() != 0) {
           $('#Locality').append("<div><input type='text' class='field' value='" + $(this).find( "option:selected").text() + "' disabled/><input type=\"button\" class='removeBtn' value=\"Remove\" id=\"removeBtn\" /></div>");
           $(this).find("option:selected").remove();
         }
         $('.removeBtn').on('click', function () { 
            $(this).parent().remove();
            var text = '<option>' + $(this).parent().find('input').val() + '</option>';
            $("#location").append(text);
         });
      });
  });
```

Comment: Its also partially works for me i.e. when i select one option and remove this one option, it add to select list normally, but when i add two option and remove any one, then it add two, three or five same remove option in selectlist.

Comment: I think it happens because i have use the class "removeBtn" when i hit any remove button.

Comment: when i select three option and remove any one, then it add seven same remove option.